# Single Tap Gesture not working on sub view that was added programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, addsubview

Background:
I used to have a touch gesture detector on a view, and it worked fine.
Then my app grew, and now I need to add that same gesture detector to 3 views.

The Problem:
The gesture detector is never called when I add it to a views, that have been attached to a parent view with ".addSubview"

The Code:

```
    parentView.addSubview(waveview)
    parentView.addSubview(waveviewCap)
    parentView.addSubview(waveviewCapBG)

    let singleFingerDTap:UITapGestureRecognizer=UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "handleWaveviewTap")
    singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    self.waveview!.addGestureRecognizer(singleFingerDTap)
    self.waveviewCap!.addGestureRecognizer(singleFingerDTap)
    self.waveviewCapBG!.addGestureRecognizer(singleFingerDTap)
```

Comment: Did you try `userInteractionEnabled` ?

Comment: I believe that you shouldn't add same gesture object at different views. Try use different gestures just with same selector

Answer (score 0):

Please add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your parent view.And update the "shouldReceiveTouch" delegate method.

```
  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    if touch.view == waveview || touch.view == waveviewCap || touch.view == waveviewCapBG {

        return true

    }
    return false
}
```

Hope its working...